# Designing backend for Mobile app?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications, mobile-application, spring-restcontroller

I have web application where typical flow is

`HTML form submission  > MVC Controller(spring) > Services(Fetch data)`

Ultimately most of the controllers methods returns html data

Now I need to develop mobile app also. Per mine understanding I need to create new Rest Controllers to return the JSON data.

Mobile app will connect to rest controller whereas web app will continue to connect to web controller already in place. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on how your controllers are written.

If your controller actions resemble REST like actions you could use spring mvc [content negotiation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) to return html or json depending on the request.

Comment: most of mine current controller methods return html data

Comment: For spring mvc content negotiation to work, you need to return model objects from the controller so that view resolver can delegate to either a html or json view.

Comment: Actually what I meant was most of mine controller method does two things 1) Return string which view resolver resolves for jsp 2) Add data in model which jsp uses  while rendering. I believe what you are suggesting is `Combining Data and Presentation Formats` section in the link you posted or the last approach `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver ` with single method .

Comment: I liked the last approach with `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver  `where there can be single method and controller can just add the domain object in model and return string (specifying the view name).  Now view resolves will resolves the view name based on expected output content type. I believe I just need to add the more views like Json view and spring will do its magic. with second approach I can just add new method for returning json data but that's more work

Comment: Yes it would potentially give you cleaner code (less controllers), but may be more trouble than it's worth if you have to refactor existing controllers and jsp views. You may also want json content type in your REST posts but html form posts for your html code which would be another challenge.

Comment: for approach with `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver `, I don't have to change anything controller. I just  need to add viewResolvers (which can be xml based or annotation). Now if expected response type is json spring will pick the jsonResolver  and if is it is html, htmlResolver will be picked. Yes while sending the request I believe I need to specify the expected response types. Is not it ?

Comment: the view resolver can look at many things.  Usually it is configured to look at the `Accept` header and/or the file extension in the url.